# How to plot Fry Graph and Raygor Graph Readability using Python?

Tags: python, text, readability

Do you have any suggestion on how to plot the Fry Graph and Raygor Graph Readability using Python? Purpose: Both readability formulas will visually plot the grade level on a chart. The number between the two parallel lines represents the U.S. grade level for example: https://readabilityformulas.com/freetests/fry-graph.php

[Fry Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SUmU.png)
[Raygor Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYc7y.png)

the following code are used to calculate the formulas:

```
import textstat

# raygor
raygor_of_keys = dict()
raygor_of_keys_to_ignore = dict()

from_y = 27
for y in range(3, 6):
    for x in range(6, from_y):
        raygor_of_keys_to_ignore[f"{y}:{x}"] = 0
    from_y = from_y - 8

to_y = 44
for y in range(7, 29):
    to_y = to_y - 1
    for x in reversed(range(to_y, 45)):
        raygor_of_keys_to_ignore[f"{y}:{x}"] = 0

raygor_number = 3
for y in range(3, 29):
    if y % 2 == 0:
        raygor_number = raygor_number + 1
    for x in range(6, 45):
        the_key = f"{y}:{x}"
        if raygor_of_keys_to_ignore.get(the_key) == 0:
            continue
        raygor_of_keys[the_key] = raygor_number


def get_value_from_raygor_graph(y_value, x_value):
    return raygor_of_keys.get(f"{y_value}:{x_value}", 0) * 2


# fry
fry_of_keys = dict()
fry_of_keys_to_ignore = dict()

from_y = 128
for y in range(2, 5):
    for x in range(108, from_y):
        fry_of_keys_to_ignore[f"{y}:{x}"] = 0
    from_y = from_y - 8

to_y = 172
for y in range(7, 26):
    to_y = to_y - 2
    for x in reversed(range(to_y, 173)):
        fry_of_keys_to_ignore[f"{y}:{x}"] = 0

fry_number = 1
for y in reversed(range(2, 26)):
    if y % 2 == 0:
        fry_number = fry_number + 1
    for x in range(108, 173):
        the_key = f"{y}:{x}"
        if fry_of_keys_to_ignore.get(the_key) == 0:
            continue
        fry_of_keys[the_key] = fry_number


def get_value_from_fry_graph(y_value, x_value):
    return fry_of_keys.get(f"{y_value}:{x_value}", 0)

def count_raygor_readability(data_list):
    sentence_numbers = 0
    words_count_bigger_six = 0
    # computation
    words_count = 0
    for sentence in data_list:
        sentence_numbers = sentence_numbers + 1
        words_count = words_count + textstat.lexicon_count(sentence)
        words_count_bigger_six = words_count_bigger_six + len([1 for n in sentence.split() if len(n) > 6])
        if words_count >= 50:
            break

    # computation
    words_count = 0
    for sentence in reversed(data_list):
        sentence_numbers = sentence_numbers + 1
        words_count = words_count + textstat.lexicon_count(sentence)
        words_count_bigger_six = words_count_bigger_six + len([1 for n in sentence.split() if len(n) > 6])
        if words_count >= 50:
            break

    return get_value_from_raygor_graph(sentence_numbers, words_count_bigger_six)


def count_fry_readability(data_list):
    sentence_numbers = 0
    syllables_numbers = 0
    # computation
    words_count = 0
    for sentence in data_list:
        sentence_numbers = sentence_numbers + 1
        syllables_numbers = syllables_numbers + textstat.syllable_count(sentence)
        words_count = words_count + textstat.lexicon_count(sentence)
        if words_count >= 150:
            break

    # computation
    words_count = 0
    for sentence in reversed(data_list):
        sentence_numbers = sentence_numbers + 1
        syllables_numbers = syllables_numbers + textstat.syllable_count(sentence)
        words_count = words_count + textstat.lexicon_count(sentence)
        if words_count >= 150:
            break

    avg_sentence_numbers = round(sentence_numbers / 3)
    avg_syllables_numbers = round(syllables_numbers / 3)

    return get_value_from_fry_graph(avg_sentence_numbers, avg_syllables_numbers)

text=" Your list is now clean enough that you can begin analyzing its contents in meaningful ways. Counting the frequency of specific words in the list can provide illustrative data. Python has an easy way to count frequencies, but it requires the use of a new type of variable: the dictionary. Before you begin working with a dictionary, consider the processes used to calculate frequencies in a list."
raygorReadability=count_raygor_readability(text)
fryReadability=count_fry_readability(text)
fryReadability
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! It looks both of your image links lead to the same graph image.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Sergey, I have updated the links. Moreover, I tried to plot it. But, I have problem in the yticks. The space between tick labels is not equal. The following code is used to plot the figure [Raygor Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaT2x.png).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter, MaxNLocator

raygory_lines2 = {3:[(8,5.8),(24,13.5)],4:[(10,5.5),(26,12)],5:[(11,4.9),(28,10.7)],
                  6:[(13,4.6),(30,10.2)], 7:[(18,4),(32,10)],8:[(23,3.8),(34,9.7)],
                  9:[(24,3.7),(35,8.5)],10:[(27,3.5),(36,7.8)],11:[(29,3.5),(38,7.8)],
                  12:[(32,3.3),(40,7.7)],13:[(36,3.21),(42,6.7)]                                             
                  }

def circle(x, y, radius=0.5):
    from matplotlib.patches import Circle
    from matplotlib.patheffects import withStroke
    circle = Circle((x, y), radius, clip_on=False, zorder=10, linewidth=1,
                    edgecolor='black', facecolor=(0, 0, 0, .0125),
                    path_effects=[withStroke(linewidth=5, foreground='w')])
    ax.add_artist(circle)


def text(x, y, text,color='blue'):
    ax.text(x, y, text, backgroundcolor="white",
            ha='center', va='center', weight='bold', color=color)

#long sentences
from_y = 27
x_sent=[]
y_sent=[]
for y in range(3, 6):
    for x in range(6, from_y):
      x_sent.append(x)
      y_sent.append(y)
      # raygor_of_keys_to_ignore[f"{y}:{x}"] = 0
    from_y = from_y - 8

#long words
to_y = 44
x_word=[]
y_word=[]
for y in range(7, 29):
    to_y = to_y - 1
    for x in reversed(range(to_y, 45)):
      x_word.append(x)
      y_word.append(y)
      # raygor_of_keys_to_ignore[f"{y}:{x}"] = 0
      
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,12))
tick_spacing = 1
k2=3
for i in raygory_lines2.keys():
  x1,x2=raygory_lines2[i][0][0],raygory_lines2[i][1][0]
  y1,y2=raygory_lines2[i][0][1],raygory_lines2[i][1][1]
  # Blue plot
  circle((x1+x2)/2, (y1+y2)/2)
  text((x1+x2)/2, (y1+y2)/2, k2)
  plt.plot([x1,x2], [y1,y2], 'ro-')
  k2=k2+1

ax.set_xticks([i for i in range(6,46,2)])
y_label1=[28, 23.0, 19.0, 16.0, 13.5, 12.0, 10.2, 9.0, 7.7, 
               6.9, 6.3, 5.7, 5.2, 4.9, 4.6, 4.3, 4.0, 3.8, 3.6,
               3.4, 3.2]
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MultipleLocator(1))
ax.set_yticks(y_label1)
ax.yaxis.set_ticklabels([str(y3) for y3 in y_label1])
# ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(tick_spacing))

ax.set_title('Raygor Graph')
ax.set_xlabel('Value')
ax.axvline(x=18, linestyle='--')
ax.axhline(y=16, linestyle='--')  
circle(18, 16)
text(18, 16, 'G','red')

tex = r'Long words'
text1='Long Sentence'
ax.text(37, 25, tex, fontsize=10, va='bottom')
ax.text(8, 5.5, text1, fontsize=10, va='bottom')

# ax.fill_between([6,8,10],[4,3.4,3.2], interpolate=True)
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
fig.tight_layout()
ax.tick_params(direction='in', length=6, width=2, colors='r', right=True, labelright='on')
#ax.fill_between([18,36,44,44],[28,12,7,28],1, interpolate=True)  
plt.show()
```